# Special characters using ALT + ASCII code

Tags: firefox

I often have to type special characters like ê (ALT 1 3 6) or ë (ALT 1 3 7). For some reason, some of them work and others don't - or at least have unintended effects.

If I type ALT 1 3 6 for instance, I get a ê character no problem but when I hit ALT 1 3 7 (which should give ë) Firefox sees it as some kind of a shortcut to open the startup page (and in the search box puts the ë character).

Where can I see what ALT 1 3 7 means to Firefox other than to simply insert the special character ë?

I'm using Firefox 39.0.3